# Should I Bypass the USB fuses on the revision 1 Raspberry Pi?

Tags: usb, fuses

As blogged on [raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1929), the USB fuses are no longer on some of the later revision 1 PCBs or the revision 2 PCBs

> USB Output Power
>
> The resetable fuses protecting the USB outputs have been removed. This
>   feature was implemented on some later revision 1.0 PCBs by replacing
>   the fuses with links; revision 2.0 permanently implements this
>   modification. It is now possible to reliably power the RPI from a USB
>   hub that back feeds power, but it is important that the chosen hub
>   cannot supply more than 2.5A under fault conditions.

Is is relatively safe to bypass them on my Raspberry Pi so I can use a wider range of keyboards/wifi/harddrive with less problems?

Comment: Yes- You can replace them with links- just like some later versions of 1.0. Just like in your comment. The 2.5A thing is not to burn the PCB traces in case you drop a screw on your GPIO and the USB hub feeds more than 2.5A- Pi will burn.

Answer (score 5):

> Is is relatively safe to bypass them on my Raspberry Pi so I can use a wider range of keyboards/wifi/harddrive with less problems?

If the modification is done properly, yes it's safe. The key thing to look out for is the bit that you quoted - if the hub can supply more than 2.5A and something goes wrong, things may get damaged!